# Comparison operators in generic heap

Tags: java, heap

For my data structures class our homework is to create a generic heap ADT. In the siftUp() method I need to do comparison and if the parent is smaller I need to do a swap.  The problem I am having is that the comparison operators are not valid on generic types.  I believe I need to use the Comparable interface but from what I read it’s not a good idea to use with Arrays.  I have also search this site and I have found good information that relates to this post none of them helped me find the solution

I removed some of the code that wasn’t relevant
Thanks

```
public class HeapQueue<E> implements Cloneable  {   
  private int highest;
  private Integer manyItems;
  private E[] data; 

  public HeapQueue(int a_highest) {
      data = (E[]) new Object[10];
      highest = a_highest;

  } 

  public void add(E item, int priority) {
      // check to see is priority value is within range
      if(priority < 0 || priority > highest) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
          ("Priority value is out of range: " + priority);
      }     
      // increase the heaps capacity if array is out of space
      if(manyItems == data.length)
        ensureCapacity();
      manyItems++;
      data[manyItems - 1] = item;
      siftUp(manyItems - 1);
  }

  private void siftUp(int nodeIndex) {
      int parentIndex;
      E tmp;
       if (nodeIndex != 0) {
            parentIndex = parent(nodeIndex);
            if (data[parentIndex] < data[nodeIndex]) {  <-- problem ****
                  tmp = data[parentIndex];
                  data[parentIndex] = data[nodeIndex];
                  data[nodeIndex] = tmp;
                  siftUp(parentIndex);
            }
        }
      } 

  private int parent(int nodeIndex) {
      return (nodeIndex - 1) / 2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading this right, E simply needs to extend [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and then your problem line becomes...

```
if (data[parentIndex].compareTo(ata[nodeIndex]) < 0)
```

This is not breaking any bet-practice rules that I know of.

Comment: When I extend E on Comparable I get a casting error in the constructor
data = (E[]) new Object[10];
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
class HeapQueue<E extends Comparable<E>>

Comment: @Char: just use ArrayList<E> instead.

Comment: I figured out the casting error... I forgot to change Object to type Comparable. Thanks for the help

Comment: It would be much nicer if I did the assignment requirements are to use arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you're using the comparable interface on on item, not an array.  One item in the array specifically.  I think the best solution here is to accept, in the constructor, a Comparator that the user can pass to compare his generic objects.

```
Comparator<E> comparator;
public HeapQueue(int a_highest, Comparator<E> compare)
{
    this.comparator = compare;
```

Then, you would store that comparator in a member function and use

```
if (comparator.compare(data[parentIndex],data[nodeIndex]) < 0)
```

In place of the less than operator.

Comment: I have not used a Comparator before, how do you add it to the constructor? Thanks